# Need help making a second data table with boolean values based on if a row exists in a first data table

Tags: r, dataframe, boolean, tibble

The idea is to make a data table or matrix or tibble which is full of boolean values base on if a row exists in a separate data table.

The idea is to go from this:

```
USER1  USER2
0001   0002
0001   0003
0001   0004
0002   0001
0002   0004
```

To a table/matrix/tibble/data frame that looks like this

```
USERID  0001  0002  0003  0004
0001    FALSE TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
0002    TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

I feel like I could use a gather or some sort of mapply but nothing has worked so far. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `table(d$USER1, d$USER2) > 0`

Comment: To clarify, this is all in R.

Answer (score 1):

### data

You need to first create a new column `val`.

```
df <- read_delim("USER1  USER2
0001   0002
0001   0003
0001   0004
0002   0001
0002   0004",delim = " ") %>%
    mutate_all(str_trim) %>%
    mutate(val = TRUE)
colnames(df) <- str_trim(colnames(df))
```

### Answer

After you append a new column, you need to get unique values from both columns, and use `expand.grid()` to get all combinations. After that, use the combination data frame to left join your original data frame. If the value column is NA, then it means the combination doesn't exist in the original data frame.

```
expand.grid(unique(df$USER1),unique(df$USER2),stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
    rename(USER1 = Var1,
           USER2 = Var2) %>%
    left_join(df) %>%
    mutate(val = ifelse(is.na(val),FALSE,TRUE)) %>%
    dcast(USER1 ~ USER2,value.var = "val")
```

```
  USER1  0001  0002  0003 0004
1  0001 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
2  0002  TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @d.b's approach in comments but using `xtabs` instead of `table`

```
xtabs(data = df) > 0

#      USER2
#USER1   0001  0002  0003 0004
#  0001 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
#  0002  TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

Or to be specific and explicitly mentioning column names

```
xtabs(~USER1 + USER2, data = df) > 0
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(USER1 = c("0001", "0001", "0001", "0002", "0002"
), USER2 = c("0002", "0003", "0004", "0001", "0004")), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```